# Static local vs local. Which one is faster in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

Below func is executed and reenterred in multi threads.
How about changing the local variables, a and len to static local variables?
Each time entered, func executes strlen.
Strlen is enough to be executed one time in this logic.
I know local variables are more faster from related postings though.

```
void func() {
  char *a = "asddf......":
  int len = strlen(a);
}
```

Comment: You can get the length of a string literal with `sizeof` at compile time. `const char str[] = "Hello, World!"; constexpr auto str_len = sizeof(str) - 1;`.

Comment: No need for `a` or `str` either. Just `sizeof("asddf.....") - 1;`

Comment: If they are static, you will need to lock them with a mutex, making them very slow. And if this matters to you, benchmark both cases yourselg, for your specific use case.

Comment: How about you use a profiler and make your own determination which one is faster

Comment: static local variables are very expensive.  They have a thread-safe initialization guarantee since C++11, it is not for free.  The snippet gives no hint that his is something you'd actually benefit from, a literal has no sharing problem since it is read-only.

Comment: C people fight with C++ people in pubs. Don't cause a brawl by mentioning both languages.

Comment: @juanchopanza I highly suspect that both, the string and its length will be used somewhere, making the literal-sizeof a less sexy choice than the const char array.

Answer (score 4):

You worry *way* too much about the small details.

As an example, the MSVC 2017 compiler transforms this

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char *a = "asddf......";
  auto len = strlen(a);

  return (int) len;
}
```

into

```
00007FF60D331000  mov         eax,0Bh  
00007FF60D331005  ret
```

So `strlen` for a string literal is a compile time constant, even if first assigned to a pointer.